# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base tomcat\webapps\appdata does not exist or is not a readable directory

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I had a WAR previously deployed on my local Tomcat (6.0.35) instance called `appdata.war`, and so the webapps directory looked like:

```
webapps/
    docs/
    examples/
    host-manager/
    manager/
    appdata/ (exploded WAR)
    ROOT/
    appdata.war
```

I deleted `appdata/` and `appdata.war` (so that Tomcat wouldn't try to redeploy it) and then added a new war (`appmon-qa.war`) to this directory.  I then ran the Tomcat startup script and saw deployment errors referencing the "old" `appdata` WAR. I poked around and saw a folder with that name located at `${TOMCAT.HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/appdata` and I deleted it (again, just to prevent Tomcat from re-deploying it). I then re-ran the startup scripts and am seeing this in the catalina log:

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps\appdata does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:        
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    ...rest of stacktrace omitted for brevity
Jun 7, 2012 11:35:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jun 7, 2012 11:35:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jun 7, 2012 11:35:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/appdata] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 7, 2012 11:35:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/appdata] has not been started
Jun 7, 2012 11:35:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive appmon-qa.war
Jun 7, 2012 11:35:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 7, 2012 11:35:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/appmon-qa] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I **assume** that my oh-so-perfectly-written `appmon-qa.war` app is failing to deploy because of some ghost reference to this old `appdata.war` app. If so, do I (properly) undeploy or delete it from Tomcat altogether so that it doesn't cause problems for my new app?

Otherwise, if this log output indicates that there is something wrong with `appmon-qa.war` itself, then where do I start debugging? Usually these "failed due to previous errors" output also includes a reason or source of what the errors are; this output is pretty undescriptive and vague. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `${TOMCAT.HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost/appdata.xml` and delete it if it exists.

Comment: Thanks @adarshr but there are no XML files inside that `localhost` directory. I do see `localhost/appdata/` but it is an empty directory. When I delete it and re-run the startup script the same thing happens but the `localhost/appdata/` directory is re-created! (Obviously there is something referencing `appdata` internally!) Does Tomcat use an embedded DB or something?!?

Comment: You could be having the `appdata.war` file present inside `webapps` or a similar other hot-deploy directory. If you keep the `.war` file there, it would get auto exploded and deployed.

Comment: As my original post explains I removed both the WAR and the exploded directory from webapps - are there are hidden/deeply-nested directories where Tomcat 6.0.35 copies WARs to or references them from?

Comment: No. You could also completely clear the `temp` and the `work` directories and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error (Document base ... does not exist or is not a readable directory).  The easy solution was to re-install Tomcat over the existing one (ignore the warning "cannot install service" because it is already there).